# What does f: 'a -> b' -> c' -> d' mean in ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

If I have a function f defined as

```
f: 'a -> 'b -> c' -> d'
```

Does that mean it takes one argument? Or 3? And then it outputs one argument? How would I use or call such a function?

Comment: It means both, depending on perspective. OCaml is a curried language, which means functions take exactly one argument but can also return another function which takes another argument and so forth. To make this more convenient there is syntax to make it seem like a function takes multiple arguments. I suggest reading about this in a proper book or tutorial, like [this](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2020fa/textbook/hop/currying.html), as they tend to explain it better, and you can easily reference related topics required that you might not already understand as well.

Comment: Plus, arguments are inputs...not outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Glennsl notes in the comments, it means both.

Very briefly, and by no means comprehensively, from an academic perspective, no function in OCaml takes more than *one* argument or returns more or less than *one* value. For instance, a function that takes a single argument and adds `1` to it.

```
fun x -> x + 1
```

We can give that function a name in one of two ways:

```
let inc = fun x -> x + 1
```

Or:

```
let inc x = x + 1
```

Either way, inc has the type `int -> int` which indicates that it takes an `int` and returns an `int` value.

Now, if we want to add *two* ints, well, functions only take *one* argument... But functions are first class things, which means a function can create and return another function.

```
let add = 
  fun x -> 
    fun y -> x + y
```

Now `add` is a function that takes an argument `x` and returns a function that takes an argument `y` and returns the sum of `x` and `y`.

We could use a similar method to define a function that adds three ints.

```
let add3 =
  fun a -> 
    fun b -> 
      fun c -> a + b + c
```

The type of `add` would be `int -> int -> int` and `add3` would have type `int -> int -> int -> int`.

Of course, OCaml is not purely an academic language, so there is convenience syntax for this.

```
let add3 a b c = a + b + c
```

**Inferred types**

In your question, you ask about a type `'a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd`. The examples provided work with the concrete type `int`. OCaml uses type inferencing. The compiler/interpreter looks at the entire program to figure out at compile time what the types should be, without the programmer having to explicitly state them. In the examples I provided, the `+` operator only works on values of type `int`, so the compiler *knows* `inc` will have type `int -> int`.

However, if we defined an identity function:

```
let id x = x
```

There is nothing her to say what type `x` should have. In fact, it can be anything. But what can be determined, if that the function will have the same type for argument and return value. Since we can't put a concrete type on that, OCaml uses a placeholder type `'a`.

If we created a function to build a tuple from two values:

```
let make_tuple x y = (x, y)
```

We get type `'a -> 'b -> 'a * 'b`.

**In conclusion**

So when you ask about:

```
f: 'a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd
```

This is a function `f` that takes three arguments of types `'a`, `'b`, and `'c` and returns a value of type `'d`.

Comment: Note: your answer treats `c'` and `d'` as though they're typos. They could be abbreviations (`type c' = int`, etc.). I feel this is more likely as `'a -> 'b` isn't inhabited in general (i.e. you need type system tricks to define a term which has such a type). The only valid definition for `f` that I can think of which would have the type `'a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd` is `let f _ _ = Obj.magic`. Otherwise, `f` would need to be a parameter or exist in some other context where it's unified with concrete types.